# JList using LinkedList?

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have an inventory program that I am in the midst of creating. It can add, edit, and delete items displayed in a JList (that's what I'm working on).  Currently I can load a file and read it's contents. I then have a save dialog which can save the read contents into a file. This is all currently done through a linked list.

The problem comes with integrating it with the GUI. I have an add, modify, and delete option in the menu bar.
I had the delete option partially working, I loaded the LinkedList invList into a DefaultListModel modelInvList.
This allowed me to display my inventory how I wanted it in the JList (of course I would loop through the LinkedList):

```
String element = "Item: " + curInv.getDesc() + " Location: " + curInv.getLoc() + 
          " Value: $" + curInv.getValue() + " Purchased: " + curInv.getMonth() + "/" +
           curInv.getDay() + "/" + curInv.getYear();
modelInvList.addElement(element);
```

Displaying (example):
Item: car Location: Garage Value: $5000.00 Purchase: 2/12/2003

The linkedlist also has a getImageLoc field, but this is not displayed in the JList (only when user goes to modify an item).
This worked...kind of. I also have it where the defaultlistmodel would be rebuilt to only show items in a certain location. When I deleted an item from the Jlist (remove at selected index), the index didn't match up with the linkedlist (deleting the wrong item).
So I'm wondering how to more directly display my linkedlist in the JList...or should I use something other than linkedlist? I also need to be able to sort the items in the JList...haven't gotten that far yet.